# async await ionic Storage get

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, async-await, storage

I thought to be smart creating a little snippet code that can both fetch and set some data to the local storage with Ionic and Storage. My helper function looks like:

```
async local(key, value?:any) {
    if(value === undefined) {
        return await this.storage.get(key);
    }

    return this.storage.set(key, value);
}
```

But when I call it from another typescript file like `let var = this.helperProvider.local('myTestVar');` I get a 'magic' object as a response:

```
t {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
__zone_symbol__state
:
true
__zone_symbol__value
:
null
__proto__
:
Object
```

Is the above possible so my `local()` method just returns the value in the local storage?

Answer (score 1):

The magic object is also a promise you need to `await`. Try calling it in another `async` function:

```
(async function() {
    let val = await this.helperProvider.local('myTestVar');
    console.log(val);
})()
```

Or use `then`

```
this.helperProvider.local('myTestVar').then(val => console.log(val));
```